# Factory method in C++: why additional Creator interface and does factory method need a class?

Tags: c++, factory

I am currently unclear what constitutes the Factory Pattern in C++ given many implementations and examples in the wild.

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/cpp/example gives an example which is one step more complex (as it implements abstract class `Creator` and then for each of the two product types a separate inherited creator classes) than many other I have seen e.g.: here: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/cpp/1

I have adapted the code from https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/cpp/example by keeping just one `Creator` class and using the `switch` statement to decide which class to return.

1. Does the below still implement the Factory Design Pattern?
2. Do I even need `Creator` class in my implementation - the `FactoryMethod()` could be just a function.
3. What is the true purpose of the abstract `Creator` class in https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/cpp/example and does using it actually make the pattern into *Abstract Factory*?

```
#include <iostream>

class Product {
public:
    virtual ~Product() {}
    virtual std::string Operation() const = 0;
};

class ConcreteProduct1 : public Product {
public:
    std::string Operation() const override {
        return "ConcreteProduct1 is in operation.\n";
    }
};
class ConcreteProduct2 : public Product {
public:
    std::string Operation() const override {
        return "ConcreteProduct2 is in operation.\n";
    }
};

class Creator {
public:
    virtual ~Creator() {};
    public:
        Product* FactoryMethod(int id) const {
            switch (id){
            case 1:
                return new ConcreteProduct1();
            case 2:
                return new ConcreteProduct2();
            default:
                break;
            }
    }
};


int main() {
    std::cout << "Launched with Creator - generating Product 1.\n";
    Creator creator;
    Product* prod1 = creator.FactoryMethod(1);
    std::cout << prod1->Operation();

    std::cout << "Launched with Creator - generating Product 2.\n";
    std::cout << "(Using the same instance of Creator)\n";

    Product* prod2 = creator.FactoryMethod(2);
    std::cout << prod2->Operation();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That seems c++ code written by a java developer, I wouldn't learn from the style shown in the examples you link

Comment: @MatG Which parts do you dislike specifically for C++ style programming? @ userPrimeNumber You should not use `new`/`delete` here, but `make_unique` and return a `std::unique_ptr` from the factory. Please see that they mention the `Creator` classes would be not primarily a factory, but would be doing business logic. So the example sketches the usage, but should not be rigidly followed.

Comment: Often in C++ classes, which are created by factories, have `private` constructors so that only friends can create them.

Comment: @Sebastian Naked `new`s, memory leaks, exception unsafety

Comment: @Sebastian I will look into smart pointers usage instead

Comment: @MatG what would be a good reference for a more idiomatic C++ implementation factory?

Comment: @userPrimeNumber I have no idea, but I think there was an interesting presentation about that at cppcon2021

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463424/using-smart-pointers-with-factory-pattern/48463652#48463652

Comment: Or this about private constructors and factories: https://seanmiddleditch.github.io/enabling-make-unique-with-private-constructors/